# How can you determine if Control.Visible is set via property or if the value is inherited

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to find a way to determine if the Visible property of a control is set via a property change or if is inheriting it value from its parent.  Using the Reflector, I find that the functions this.GetVisibleCore() and this.GetState() are both internal methods so I cannot call them.

The widgets themselves are created dynamically so I do not want to attach a method to the VisibleChanged event just after the creation of each widget so can try to monitor this property.  If I have to, I guess I will but I am looking for something just a bit more elegant.

Edit

What I really want to know is when I hide the form and go to close it or build the form but keep it hidden, what Visible values are false because the form is hidden and what values are false because they were set to false.  Again I do not want to have to attach a method to each VisibleChanged event of each widget.  I just want to somehow read it off the Control object.

Comment: Very unclear.  You want to find out if the Visible property was overridden?

Comment: No.  I want to find out when the Visible property is set.  All Control Visible properties are false when the form itself is hidden or just has not been shown yet.  When the form is visible, then all of the visible properties switch to true unless you have set them false somewhere with in the code.  Hide the form and the Visible property becomes false.  What I want to know is how to find out if a Control has had the Visible property set and what is its value regardless of the Shown/Hidden state of the form/container it has been assigned to as a child.

Comment: Maybe you can create a helper function that loops through all the controls to create an array of all the visible controls.  Then you can then use this list to SHOW/HIDE the form controls regardless of what's been changed since it was loaded.  I assume you just want to be able to SHOW/HIDE a customized form.

Comment: Just because a control has been set to Visible does not mean its Visible property is going to be true.  If its container's Visible property is false, then the controls Visible property is going to be false.  The Visible=true is stored in a state field in the Control class and is only accessed with the Parent is Visible -- the parent object always has the right to override the child.  I want to get to that state variable in some form or fashion, the private state variable that is accessed through internal methods, so I can see if there has been a value assigned and if so, what is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not very clear, but I assume that the problem is that the Visible property getter returns the actual visibility state of the control.  Which is not just the last assigned value to Visible, it also takes account of whether the parents of the control are visible.  In other words, if you've got a button in a UserControl and the UserControl's Visible = false then the button's Visible will always be false as well.

You can override SetVisibleCore() to find out if the control intends to be visible:

```
public bool CouldBeVisible { get; set; }

protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
  CouldBeVisible = value;
  base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to get to the actual value but I guess this can work.  The only drawbacks I see are that I need to create a custom widget inheriting from the base widget I want to track the Visible property ( Form, Textbox, Label, MenuItem, etc ) and I need to identify that the value of CouldBeVisible needs to be assigned to the Visible property.